# program outputs all 0s after shell sort

Tags: c++

I'm doing a program for my data structures class where I take in an array of 25 random numbers from 50 to 100, then sort them out using shell sort. The program first asks how many numbers in the array are going to be used, then sets the seed for the random number generator. The third input is the number of gap values, and any other inputs after that are gap values.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int NUMBERS_SIZE = 25;
const int GAPS_SIZE = 5;

void insertionSortInterleaved(int numbers[], int numbersSize, int startIndex, int gap)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (i = i + gap; i < numbersSize; i += gap) {
        j = i;
        while (j - gap >= startIndex && numbers[j] < numbers[j - gap]) {
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[j - gap];
            numbers[j - gap] = temp;
            j = j - gap;
        }
    }
}

void shellSort(int numbers[], int numbersSize, int gapValues[], int gaps)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    int gapValue = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < gaps; j++) {
        gapValue = gapValues[j];
        for (i = 0; i < gapValue; i++) {
            insertionSortInterleaved(numbers, numbersSize, i, gapValue);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; //maximum size of 25
    int gapValues[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; //maximum size of 5
    int nums = 0;
    int seed = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int gaps = 0;

    cin >> nums; //example input: 10
    cin >> seed; //example input: 40
    cin >> gaps; //example input: 3

    for (int k = 0; k < gaps; k++) { 
        cin >> gapValues[k]; //example input: 5 3 1
    }

    srand(seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
        numbers[i] = (rand() % 51) + 50;
    }

    cout << "UNSORTED: ";
    for (i = 0; i < nums; ++i) {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    shellSort(numbers, NUMBERS_SIZE, gapValues, gaps);

    cout << "SORTED: ";
    for (i = 0; i < nums; ++i) {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

So if I input the example they used in the problem, which was `"10 40 3 5 3 1"`, I get the following output:

```
UNSORTED: 88 60 61 71 65 75 70 96 74 56 
SORTED: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

As you can see, the sorted array is all 0s, when it should be

```
SORTED: 56 60 61 65 70 71 74 75 88 96.
```

I tried debugging this, but it didn't give me anything. I honestly don't know what's wrong here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I recommend correcting the indentation by using spaces and not tabs.  This will make your code easier to read.

Comment: This looks exactly like a question that was deleted a couple of hours ago, even right down to the variable names.  I asked to add the data to the program instead of using `cin`, and for some reason, that was a difficult task.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Si, Señor!

Comment: *I tried debugging this, but it didn't give me anything* -- The debugger has no idea what you're program is supposed to do.  The debugger's purpose is to allow you to step through the program, watch variables, watch the flow, set breakpoints, etc. You are then to see if the program, variables, flow, etc. is following the logic you intended.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you're the same person or not, but it was asked that instead of random numbers, hard-code the data into the program.  [Here is the example of what should be expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66358465a415b2bd).  The only thing missing is `gaps` and the number of gaps.  So replace the `0` with the gaps data, and change the number of gaps appropriately.  *Then* you would have a [mcve], which is what is required here.

Comment: How did you try to debug your program? Debuggers aren't magic, and they won't just point out the problem to you. What they will allow you to do is to step through the program execution and do things such as look at the value of variables. I recommend you find a tutorial that can teach you to use debuggers properly.

Comment: How many numbers do you enter?  And how many are you sorting?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you. I am still kind of new on here so I don't really know how to word my questions, and I'm still fairly new to c++. I forgot to mention that you need to input the seed so then each number in the numbers[] array gets filled with one of those numbers, and the reason i'm putting cin for those is because you can input up to 25 numbers since that is the maximum size you can use for the array. I'm sorry of i caused any confusion.

Comment: @J.Doe -- The issue is that your sorting function doesn't work.  The best way to solve that immediate problem is to forget about `cin`, forget about random numbers.  Use *known* data, and place the input directly into the program.  It makes no sense to try and do random numbers now, and the sort doesn't work whatsoever.  It has to be working first before even thinking about random numbers.  That is how you develop applications -- work on the basic functionality *first* without introducing more hurdles (such as data always changing when you run the program).

Comment: So take the example I posted, and simply just fill in the `gapsValue` and `gaps` data with *known* values.  That's it.  Now debug that until you get the sort to work for those numbers.  Once you see it working, *then and only then* should you concern yourself with `rand()` and `cin`.  You're basically two lines of code from a [mcve], but for some reason you (and the other poster) are not cooperating.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for your help. Me and them are the same person, actually. I just get a bit dependent sometimes when I don't get something. I'm sorry for putting you through all this

Comment: Given the data, [this is an example of being minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a831c7f15495bbd4).  Note the data in the gaps array -- no `cin` statements, as no one wants to type data in every single time the program is run.  Now that is what you should be debugging.  Anyone can now take that code, and without changes, compile it run it, and give you reasons why it may not be working.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i get it now, thanks so much. I'll be sure to take all this into consideration next time i have a question to ask.

Comment: `for (i = i + gap; i < numbersSize; i += gap) { j = i;` -- Both `i` and `j` are out-of-bounds.  For the data you have, `cout << i` will show you that `i` is 10, which is out of bounds.  This is what you should have detected when debugging your program -- that eventually `i` will go beyond the bounds of the `numbers` array.  The valid indices of a 10 element array is `0`-`9`, so there is no valid index `10`.